# Syntax for implicit operator with class indexer

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion, indexer

I am looking for the correct syntax to use an implicit operator on a class that uses an indexer to acess a private Dictionary:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MyClass : IEnumerable
{
   private Dictionary<string, object> vars = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   public object this[string key]
   {
       get
       {
           if(vars.ContainsKey(key))
           {
                return (object)vars[key];
           }
           else
           {
               return null;
           }
       }

       set
       {
           object o = value;
           if(!vars.ContainsKey(key))
           {
               vars.Add(key, o);
           }
           else if(value == null)
           {
               vars.Remove(key);
           }
           else
           {
               vars[key] = o;
           }
        }
    }

/*some code*/

   public static implicit operator bool(WorldVars w, string i)
   {
       if(w[i] != null)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Right now the use is pretty straight forward

```
MyClass[anykey] = myValue
```

but I'd like to implement a quicker way to test the presence of a value, like:

```
if(MyClass[anykey])
   { //logic }
```

Comment: The meaning of `if(MyClass[k])` must be that the value associated with the key is true, not that the key exists in the collection!  What if the value of `MyClass[k]` existed and was *false*? That would be very confusing if this expression was treated as true.

Comment: Damn! Thanks! Too much thinking that I even lost the evidence of it -_- . Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As commenter Eric notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222007/syntax-for-implicit-operator-with-class-indexer#comment60076641_36222007), the semantics of your class would be completely broken if you were able to achieve what you're asking for. The whole point of the indexer is so that when you write the expression `myClass[anyKey]`, it evaluates to the *value* that your class associates with `anyKey`.

If you were to change the implementation so that it simply returned a `bool` value representing containment, then you'd be stuck having to implement some *other* mechanism to actually retrieve the value (e.g. a separate method). Additionally, it would also raise the question of what the setter should do.

Given the implementation you show, it seems to me that writing `if (myClass[anyKey] != null)` is not really inconvenient, and it seems reasonably expressive to me. That is, it is a reasonable way for the code to clearly express its intent.

That said, if you did want something more expressive, it would not be unreasonable to write a `ContainsKey()` method in your class for the purpose:

```
public bool ContainsKey(string key) { return vars.ContainsKey(key); }
```

Then you could check for the key's presence like:

```
if (myClass.ContainsKey[anyKey]) { ... }
```

Finally, the code you posted should work acceptably well, but it seems overly verbose and inconsistent to me. IMHO, a better way to write your indexer methods would be something like this:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        object o;

        return vars.TryGetValue(key, out o) ? o : null;
    }

    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            vars[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            vars.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

That implementation avoids things like:

- Redundant check for containment when getting a value
- Copying `value` into local variable unnecessarily when setting a value
- Having two different lines of code that each both have the effect of setting the value for a key in the dictionary

Comment: Thanks! I think I was too tired to see the obvious in front of me on this one.

Comment: It happens. :) In fact, the reason I wrote the answer was that when I considered other options for disposition of your question, I kept coming back to the thought that if you found yourself, even if just due to fatigue, struggling with the issue, it's possible someone else in the future might and would need a similar nudge in the right direction. Providing a formal answer should help ensure such people get the second look they need.